# Regular Expression with +/-

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

Is it possible to extract the sign using Regular Expression ?

For example {"Today+100","Yesterday-200"}. And I need {"Today",100,"Yesterday",-200}.

Currently, I use Regular Expression to get the sign and number. Then combine them. But I reckon there should be a better method.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
lst = {"Today+100", "Yesterday-200"};
```

#### StringSplit

```
StringSplit[lst, RegularExpression["([+-]\\d+)"] :> ToExpression@"$1"]
```

> {{"Today", 100}, {"Yesterday", -200}}

```
StringSplit[lst, n : NumberString :> ToExpression@n]
```

> {{"Today", 100}, {"Yesterday", -200}}

#### StringReplace

```
List @@@ StringReplace[lst, RegularExpression["([+-]\\d+)"] :> ToExpression@"$1"]

List @@@ StringReplace[lst, n : NumberString :> ToExpression@n]

Sequence @@@ StringReplace[lst,
   RegularExpression["(\\w+)([+-]\\d+)"] :> {"$1", ToExpression@"$2"}]

Sequence @@@ StringReplace[lst, 
  w : WordCharacter .. ~~ n : NumberString :> {w, ToExpression @ n}]
```

all give

> {{"Today", 100}, {"Yesterday", -200}}

**Note:** My original answer used the regex substring `[\\+\\-]`. I learned from @user1066's comment and answer that it can be replaced with much nicer `[+-]`.

Comment: I voted for @kglr, who is amazing. Could you explain what the ToExpression does (in the first two) for us lesser mortals?

Comment: @user1066, very good point. It  just did not occur to me:) I suggest you post that (much cleaner) form as an answer.

Comment: @MikeColacino, without `ToExpression` we get `{{"Today", "+100"}, {"Yesterday", "-200"}}`.  `ToExpression` turns  `"+100"`  into `100` and `"-200"` into `-200`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help:

```
StringCases[#, 
    WordCharacter .. | (_ ~~ DigitCharacter ..)] & /@ {"Today+100", 
   "Yesterday-200"} // Flatten
(* {"Today", "+100", "Yesterday", "-200"} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

A slight modification of @kglr's [first method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216435/106), (the one containing the neat use of `ToExpression`):

```
StringSplit[lst, 
  RegularExpression["[+-]\d{3}"]:> ToExpression["$0"]]
```

> {{Today, 100}, {Yesterday, -200}}

(Originally posted as a comment)

Comment: In addition, using `StringCases` with positive look-ahead (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216528/106) by 
Alexey Popkov: `StringCases[lst, RegularExpression["(^.+)(?=[+-])([+-]\d{3})"]:> {"$1", ToExpression["$2"]}]`

Answer (score 2):

I think OP wants to get rid of the "+" in front of the positive ones, which makes it a little more complicated.

```
ss[s_ /; StringMatchQ[s, __ ~~ "-" ~~ __]] := (str = StringSplit[s, "-"]; {str[[1]], "-" <> str[[2]]});
ss[s_ /; StringMatchQ[s, __ ~~ "+" ~~ __]] := StringSplit[s, "+"]
ss /@ {"Today+100", "Tomorrow-200"} // Flatten
```

Of course everything is a string here, which might or might not matter to OP.