# Extract the name of a point with Regular Expression

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I have a list of points as strings in the form

```
{"A1=(345.2345,3423.1)","B=(2123,97.123)","KX=(2144.546,-4455)"}
```

and I would like to extract the names using RegularExpression. For a single point I tried

```
StringCases["A1=(345.2345,3423.1)", RegularExpression["^.+\\="]]
```

but the output is

```
{"A1="}
```

How can I extract only the name (everything that is on the left of "=" at the beginning of the string) without the character "=" itself?

Comment: A slight variant of the solution already given: `StringCases[lst, RegularExpression["(^.+)[=]"]:>"$1"]` where '`lst=your_list`

Comment: In addition, maybe consider `StringSplit[lst, "="][[All,1]]` or `StringSplit[lst, RegularExpression["="]][[All,1]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = StringCases[RegularExpression["(^.+)="] :> "$1"] 

f /@ {"A1=(345.2345,3423.1)",  "B=(2123,97.123)", "KX=(2144.546,-4455)"}
```

> {{"A1"}, {"B"}, {"KX"}}

Answer (score 4):

Use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = StringCases[RegularExpression["^[^=]+(?==)"]];

f /@ {"A1=(345.2345,3423.1)", "B=(2123,97.123)", "KX=(2144.546,-4455)"}
```

> ```
> {{"A1"}, {"B"}, {"KX"}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Another way, without using regular expressions

```
StringSplit[#, "="] & /* First /@ {"A1=(345.2345,3423.1)", "B=(2123,97.123)", "KX=(2144.546,-4455)"}

{* {"A1", "B", "KX"} *)
```