# String containing characters in the same order as other string

Tags: string-manipulation

How can I write a function that checks whether the characters in the first string are in the same order as in the second string?

Examples:

```
f["ABCDE", "ABC"]
(* True *)

f["ACBDE", "ABC"]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Haven't yet figured out how to make it work, but I suspect that `SequenceAlignment` could be used here.

Comment: I'm glad this seemingly simple question led to many different approaches, thanks to all who contributed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ClearAll[alignedQ]

alignedQ = #2 == LongestCommonSequence @ ## &;
```

***Examples:***

```
exampleinputs = {{"ABCDE", "ABC"}, {"ACBDE", "ABC"}, {"ABCDE", "ABCE"}, 
 {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MOS"}, {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MSO"}, 
 {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "RTM"}, 
 {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE"}, 
 {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MISSOURI SOUHTERN STATE"}, 
 {"Hello Mathematica Stack Exchange",  "ica"}};


Grid[{##, alignedQ @ ##} & @@@ exampleinputs]
```

| str1 | str2 | alignedQ[str1,str2] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "ABCDE" | "ABC" | True |
| "ACBDE" | "ABC" | False |
| "ABCDE" | "ABCE" | True |
| "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE" | "MOS" | True |
| "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE" | "MSO" | True |
| "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE" | "RTM" | False |
| "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE" | "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE" | True |
| "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE" | "MISSOURI SOUHTERN STATE" | False |
| "Hello Mathematica Stack Exchange" | "ica" | True |

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[alignedQ2]

alignedQ2 = StringMatchQ[#, StringRiffle[Characters@#2, Table["*", 3]]] &;


alignedQ2 @@@ exampleinputs == alignedQ @@@ exampleinputs
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: nice! I wish I'd remembered LongestCommonSequence!

Comment: Nice and short solution! I always learn something new watching your contributions :-)

Answer (score 6):

This one passes all of the tests I've seen so far, but I'm still not actually sure it will work for what you want to use it for.

```
SameOrderQ[full_, abbr_] :=
  StringContainsQ[
    StringJoin[DeleteCases[SequenceAlignment[full, abbr], _List]], 
    abbr]
```

Tests:

```
SameOrderQ["ABCDE", "ABC"]
(*True*)

SameOrderQ["ACBDE", "ABC"]
(*False*)

SameOrderQ["ABCDE", "ABCE"]
(*True*)

SameOrderQ["MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MOS"]
(*True*)

SameOrderQ["MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MSO"]
(*True*)

SameOrderQ["MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "RTM"]
(*False*)

SameOrderQ["MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE"]
(*True*)

SameOrderQ["MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MISSOURI SOUHTERN STATE"]
(*False*)

SameOrderQ["Hello Mathematica Stack Exchange", "ica"]
(*True*)
```

Answer (score 5):

The following gives the desired outputs as described in the OP

```
f[a_, b_] := StringContainsQ[a, b]
f["ABCDE", "ABC"]
f["ABCDE", "ABC"]
f["ACBDE", "ABC"]
```

> [image: true]

> [image: true]

> [image: false]

Checking some more cases for completeness:

```
f["ACBDE", "BDE"]
```

> [image: true]

```
f["ABCDE", "ABCE"]
```

> [image: false]

```
f["Hello Mathematica Stack Exchange", "ica"]
```

> [image: true]

Comment: thank you for the prompt response

Comment: I just saw your solution fails with {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MOS"}?  This appears to be more complicated as first sight!

Comment: @Suite401 thanks for the comment. In your example I find it weird that you were expecting a `True` output to be honest. `S` is before the `O` in `MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE`

Comment: yes, was hoping for "True" - any thoughts for a revision?

Comment: @Suite401 yes I get that you were hoping for `True`. I don't understand the reason for that. I read your question again: `the characters in the first string are in the same order as in the second string` In the string `MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE` the `MOS` is not in that order though. Is it possible you meant something else originally?

Comment: Your test cases are helpful.   When I made the OP I didn't realize there would be more complex cases: MOS can be viewed as being in order as follows: MissOuriSouthernstate.

Comment: @Suite401 ohhh I see. so you are, also, interested in jumps as well, right?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this using `StringPosition`:

```
f = UnsameQ[StringPosition[#1, #2], {}] &;
```

Checking my mate @bmf's latest case:

```
f["Hello Mathematica Stack Exchange", "ica"]

(*True*)
```

**Edit**
Considering everything discussed with my mate @bmf and using the details provided by the author of the OP, my proposal is the following:

```
ContainsWithSkips[str_String, pattern_String] := 
Module[{regexPattern = 
        ".*" <> StringJoin[Riffle[Characters[pattern], ".*"]] <> ".*"}, 
       StringMatchQ[str, RegularExpression[regexPattern], IgnoreCase -> True]]
```

Testing `ContainsWithSkips`:

```
ContainsWithSkips["ABCDE", "ABCE"]

(*True*)

ContainsWithSkips["MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", "MOS"]

(*True*)
ContainsWithSkips["ACBDE", "ABC"]

(*False*)

ContainsWithSkips["Hello Mathematica Stack Exchange", "ica"]

(*True*)
```

Comment: Nice one as well. Check the comment section in my answer as the author of the OP is interested in something that is a bit extra ;)

Comment: Hi mate! I see, it seems that the author of the OP wants something more complicated.

Comment: f = UnsameQ[StringPosition[#1, #2], {}] &; also fails the Missouri test :/

Comment: I understand, but then the example f["ABCDE", "ABCE"] also fails, since "ABCE" is a substring that has a jump.

Comment: Yes, would hope for a True with {"ABCDE","ABCE"}

Answer (score 5):

```
StringContainsQ[___~~"A"~~___~~"B"~~___~~"C"~~___]/@{"ABCDE","ACBDE","EABCD"}

(* {True,False,True} *)
```

```
StringContainsQ[___~~"M"~~___~~"O"~~___~~"S"~~___]/@{"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE",
  "MISSOURI ZOUTHERN MATE"}

(* {True,False} *)
```

**Regular Expression**

```
StringMatchQ[RegularExpression@StringTemplate[StringRiffle[ConstantArray[".*",
  3+1],"``"]]["A","B","C"]]/@{"ABCDE","ACBDE","EABCD"}

(* {True,False,True} *)
```

```
 StringMatchQ[RegularExpression@StringTemplate[StringRiffle[ConstantArray[".*",
  3+1],"``"]]["M","O","S"]]/@{"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE","MISSOURI ZOUTHERN MATE"}

(* {True,False} *)
```

```
StringMatchQ[RegularExpression@StringTemplate[StringRiffle[ConstantArray[".*",
  5+1],"``"]]["M","I","O" ,"R","S","E"]]/@{"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE",
  "MISSOURI ZOUTHERN MATE"}

(* {True,False} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using test data from @kglr and reinventing longest common sequence using `StringExpression`:

```
lcss[{main_String, seq_String}] := 
 Module[{expr = 
    StringExpression @@ Riffle[Characters@seq, BlankNullSequence[]] //
       Append[BlankNullSequence[]] // Prepend[BlankNullSequence[]]},
  StringMatchQ[main, expr]
  ]

exampleinputs = {{"ABCDE", "ABC"}, {"ACBDE", "ABC"}, {"ABCDE", 
    "ABCE"}, {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", 
    "MOS"}, {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", 
    "MSO"}, {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", 
    "RTM"}, {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", 
    "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE"}, {"MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE", 
    "MISSOURI SOUHTERN STATE"}, {"Hello Mathematica Stack Exchange", 
    "ica"}};

lcss /@ exampleinputs
```

{True, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True}

Answer (score 5):

```
foo[{a_, b_}] := 
 MemberQ[Characters @ b] @ Subsets[Characters @ a, {StringLength @ b}]

foo /@ exampleinputs
```

{True, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True}

exampleinputs like accepted answer (kglr)

Answer (score 2):

Say s1 and s2 are strings where StringLength[s1]>=StringLength[s2].

First we check if the characters of s2 appear in s1.

Now we determine the first position of the first character  of s2 in s1 and store it in p.

Next we determine the first position of the the next character of s2 in s1 that is larger than p. If there is none, the test fails. Otherwise the position is stored in p. This is repeated over the characters of s2.

```
test[s1_, s2_] := 
 Module[{pos, cs1 = Characters[s1], cs2 = Characters[s2], p = 0, 
   res = True},
  If[! SubsetQ[cs1, cs2], Print["s2 not contained in s1"]; Return[]];
  pos = StringPosition[s1, #] & /@ cs2;
  pos = Map[#[[All, 1]] &, pos, 1];
  Do[If[Max[pos[[i]]] < p, res = False;Break[]]; 
   p = First[Select[pos[[i]], Function[x, x > p]]];
   , {i, Length[pos]}];
  res
  ]
```

Some test cases:

```
s1="MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE"

test[s1,"MSO"]
True
test[s1, "RTM"]
False

test[s1, "MISSOURI SOUTHERN STATE"]
True
```

But if we exchange T and H

```
test[s1, "MISSOURI SOUHTERN STATE"]
False
```